# Adjust Gap Opening Penalty

Tags: biopython

I am using mafft from the biopython package to align my sequences:

```
output=open("aligned.fasta","w")
from Bio.Align.Applications import MafftCommandline
mafft_cline=MafftCommandline(input="test.fasta")
print(mafft_cline)
stdout, stderr = mafft_cline()
output.write(stdout)
```

However I want to adjust the gap opening penalty (default is -6) and I want to test several ones (here -1). The help page refers to it as --LOP but I have tried several ways to change it but couldn't.

I tried:

```
mafft_cline=MafftCommandline(input="test.fasta") --LOP -1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'LOP' is not defined
```

OR

```
mafft_cline.LOP=-1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 410, in __setattr__
    self.set_parameter(name, value)  # treat as a parameter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 358, in set_parameter
    self._check_value(value, name, parameter.checker_function)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 380, in _check_value
    % (value, name))
ValueError: Invalid parameter value -1 for parameter LOP
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to set the parameter via the object property, e.g.

```
mafft_cline.lop = -1.0
```

Please note that the parameter value needs to be a float, i.e. `-1.0` and not `-1`.

Comment: Thank you very much Max. I didn't realize it had to be a float.